# MySQL Executing more SQL Statements and getting one Result

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I would like to execute more SQL Statements and get one result like lets say I have 3 Tables they all have same Column Names:

```
Table user1
User Password Email

Table user2
User Password Email

Table user3
User Password Email
```

Now I want to get all User Password Emails from all the Tables in one SQL Statement. I hope you can help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Apart from the answers below, having multiple User tables reeks of bad database normalization. When multiple entities behave the same, they should be in the same table, and possibly extended via other tables - not duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `union` will allow you to combine the record sets.

```
select user, password, email from user1
union 
select user, password, email from user2
union
select user, password, email from user3
```

Answer (score 1):

use `UNION`.

```
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM Table2
UNION 
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM Table3
```

The above query will generate unique records. If you want to keep duplicate, add `ALL`

```
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM Table3
```

Comment: You should use `UNION ALL` in this case - without the ALL it tries to undub the results.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple, use Union operator as below :

```
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM User1
UNION 
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM User2
UNION
SELECT User, PassWord, Email FROM User3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select User, Password, Email
from Table1
union all
select User, Password, Email
from Table2
union all
select User, Password, Email
from Table3
```

Answer (score 0):

Union operation is very good example for your question:

```
select user, password, email from user1
union
selection user, password, email from user2
union
select user, password, email from user3
```